# css navbar how to make the text in navbar padding from top without increasing the height of the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I tried to do following, but it increase the distance of the text in navbar from the top but also increases the height of the navbar. 
I just want my text in navbar have some padding from top. Anyone know how to do it?

```
.navbar-inner { 
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

[image: I want to increase the height for those Text from the top , how i do it?]

I want to increase the distance of the "login , register ,etc." from the top .

This code doesnt work

```
 .navbar-inner {     
   heigth:20px; 
   padding-top:20px; 
 }
```

Comment: upvoted. I see nothing wrong with this question. Not sure why people keep down-voting when they don't have an idea what they are seeing lol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to deduct the amount of padding from the height of the element.

eg. if your element is 30px high and you have 'padding-top: 10px;' then you'll have to deduct 10px from the element height. so you'll now have:

```
height: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
```

For more info read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: it seems this doesnt do what i want... i attached a pic on the top.. please take a look

Comment: .navbar-inner { 
  font-size: 12px;
  heigth:20px;
  padding-top:20px;
}    if i follow this code, it's increasing the height of my navbar, but i dont want to change the height of my navbar

Comment: if you add to one property, you'll have to deduct from the other. So if you want the padding to increase, then reduce the height by an equal amount.

Comment: the question is it doesnt work for .navbar-inner... so i am looking for someone who knows about the navbar ..